# Mui theme customization as Typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

In my MUI theme I would like to customize link as

```
  components: {
    MuiLink: {
      defaultProps: {
        component: LinkComponent,
      },
    },
  }
```

I have the following ts error

```
Type error: Type '{ component: ForwardRefExoticComponent<Omit<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, keyof InternalLinkProps> & InternalLinkProps & { ...; } & RefAttributes<...>>; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<LinkProps
>'.


  76 |     MuiLink: {
  77 |       defaultProps: {
> 78 |         component: LinkBehaviour,
     |         ^
  79 |       },
  80 |     },
```

I added

```
declare module '@mui/material/Link/Link' {
  interface LinkProps {
    component: React.ReactNode
  }
}
```

But I get another error

```
Type error: Duplicate identifier 'LinkProps'.
```

How can I make it works?

Answer (score 0):

```
    MuiLink: {
      defaultProps: {
        component: LinkBehaviour,
      } as LinkProps,
    },
```